# How to create a ListStreamPlot using two imported images

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

I have two .mat files containing xdata and ydata (each having dimensions {27,256,256}. These are kind of stacks of 256x256 images. I want to create a ListStreamPlot using a specific slice of the image cubes.

```
x=xdata[[1,All,All]];
y=ydata[[1,All,All]];
```

I used

```
ListStreamPlot[{x,y}]
```

and it doesn't give any output. Any help is appreciated..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you asked your question correctly, but w.r.t what you have asked, you want to do following.

1. You didn't provide data, so I will generate an equivalent one:

`data = Table[Table[{x, y}, {x, 1, 256, 1}, {y, 1, 256, 1}], 27];`

`x = Flatten[data[[All, All, All, 1]]];`

`y = Flatten[data[[All, All, All, 2]]];`

2. Now we need to construct `data` back from `x` and `y`:

`flatData = Flatten[MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {x, y}]];`

`pairs = Partition[#, 2] & /@ Partition[#, 256*2] & /@ Partition[flatData,256*256*2];`

3. Now you can plot all the data:

   `ListStreamPlot /@ pairs`

Comment: Thanks for this.! I actually wanted to plot just one image at a time. Playing around the expressions will do the job, hopefully..!